# Combining JointState messages from several topics

Tags: robot-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am using [ptu46 driver](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ptu46). It publishes pan and tilt joints to the /ptu/state topic using sensor_msgs/JointState. There are other nodes in my system that publish joint states to /joint_states topic. I want robot_state_publisher to listen to both /joint_states and /ptu/state topics and publish a transform tree. The reason I don't want the PTU driver to publish to /joint_states directly is that there is an action server node that listens to /ptu/state and allows controlling the PTU. Is there a way to get around this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31956/combining-jointstate-messages-from-several-topics/) by [aecins](https://answers.ros.org/users/1744/aecins/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2012-04-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, I have found a solution. You can aggregate JointState messages from several topics into a single /joint_states topic using the source list parameter of [joint_state_publisher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/joint_state_publisher#Parameters). You have to make sure that your urdf model has the joint names corresponding to those published in your JointState sources.

---

Originally posted by [aecins](https://answers.ros.org/users/1744/aecins/) with karma: 113 on 2012-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4